# Функция срабатывает на else всегда

Tags: javascript, cordova

Вообщем есть небольшая функция

```
$('.checkboxx input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var allsumma = $('.editBProgress .title span').html();
    allsumma = del_spaces(allsumma); allsumma = parseFloat(allsumma);
    console.log(allsumma); console.log(activeSumma); console.log($('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .price').html());
    var res = allsumma - (activeSumma + $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .price').html());
    if (res > 0) {
        donePay($(this).attr('id'));
    } else {
        navigator.showToast('Данная опалата больше необходимой.');
    }
});
```

при проверке в консоли она срабатывает как надо т.е. больше нуля идет другая функция, а меньше нуля ну ясно - выдает уведомление.
А при работе через js непосредственно в коде всегда выдает else и неважно больше или меньше нуля. Помогите плизз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообщем так и получилось один из данных взялся как строка поэтому не чего и не срабатывало. Вот так теперь работает:

```
$('.checkboxx input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
var allsumma = $('.editBProgress .title span').html();
allsumma = del_spaces(allsumma); allsumma = parseFloat(allsumma);
console.log(allsumma);console.log(activeSumma);console.log(parseInt($('#'+$(this).attr('id') + ' .price').html()));
var res = allsumma - (activeSumma + parseInt($('#'+$(this).attr('id') + ' .price').html()));;
if (res > 0) {
    donePay($(this).attr('id'));
} else {
    navigator.showToast('Данная опалата больше необходимой.');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Такое может быть только если переменная `res` - не число, а `NaN` ([not a numeric](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN))

Скорее всего, у вас переменная `activeSumma` имеет какое-то нечисленное значение.

Пример:

```
var a = 12.3 - ("4.5" + "6.7");
alert(a); // выведет NaN
```

И чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, нужно все слагаемые/вычитаемые приводить к численному значению через `parseFloat` или ещё как-то

Пример:

```
var a = 12.3 - (1*"4.5" + parseFloat("6.7"));
alert(a); // выведет 1.1000000000000014 в FireFox
```

Comment: нет она определенно числовая говорю же когда через консоль её прописываю все срабатывает. Скорее всего все дело в .change(), но я хз как по другому случше checkbox прописывать

Comment: @Moonwolf45 `12.3 - (4.5 + "6.7")` - тоже `NaN`, потому что результат сложения числа `4.5` и строки `"6.7"` - строка `"4.56.7"`

Comment: ну если предположить что у меня где в процессе один изданных идет как строка, то вполне возможно... надо проверить

Comment: @Moonwolf45 функция `.html()` всегда возвращает строку

Comment: да я уже допер до этого когда повнимательней посмотрел консоль; все переменные через консоль кроме этой были синие, а она черная

Comment: @Moonwolf45 значит я был прав ) отметьте один из ответов как правильный, пожалуйста